# Convert $http binary response to File object in JavaScript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file

So when I choose file from html input file button and `console.log` `document.getElementById("file_input").files[0];`, 
I get response like this : 
[image]

But when I do:

```
$http.get('file/location/filename.bin')
    .then(function (res){
        var data = res.data;
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length);
        for(var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++){
          bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        console.log(new File([bytes], 'filename'));
     });
```

Logs different file object like this :
[image]
Why am I getting different file object eventhough I'm hitting the same file in two different ways? I want to get the file object like the first image but by using `$http.get`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Update:** 
I'm trying to send the byte chunks of the file to an API server. The file from upload button works but the `$http.get` file does not work. That's why I'm trying to get the same file object.

Comment: This line is definitely not in the right syntax: `console.log(new File[bytes], 'filename');`

Comment: I believe you need to load the data into a Blob object and then possibly use a FileReader to create a file from said Blob. Not sure though. Can you give the motive behind the code? Might help find the solution, other than "I want the same object type"

Comment: sorry that was a typo, its `new File([bytes], 'filename')`

Comment: @Spidy I will try that. Also, I explained the objective by updating the question. Thank you.

Comment: How is the file being served? Most the time, HTTP responses are just the contents of a file or api response. What type of response is the server sending you?

Comment: I've captured it here: http://i.imgur.com/0VSoQVc.png